# Performing operations on items within an array - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

Sorry for this question, but I haven’t found the answer in any of the texts or sites I’ve been researching. I am trying to do something that seems like it should be easy, but I don’t understand enough about arrays to pull it off. I am trying to create an array that is some number of rows; let’s say 10 rows, by 3 columns, or Myarr(1 to 10 , 1 to 3) – and then populate it as follows in memory before pasting it back into an excel sheet. Here’s an example using very simple constants and functions, not the ones I really need to run.

The reason is that I've found that running my particular construct as set of Excel formulas and VBA custom functions is very slow and results in a recalculation problem that I have written about in this forum that is not yet solved, so I am trying a work-around that performs all operations in an array, and then just pastes the result back to Excel.

Column 1 is just the list of numbers 1 to 10

**Column 2 is the value of the previous row of Column 2 plus a constant; “Constant”; this is the part I really am puzzled by**

Column 3 is just a function of the value of this row of Column 2

For example:
Constant = 2
Function of Column 2 value is simply Column 2 value x 4

So the output should be
Value col 1, previous value col 2 + Constant, column 2 x 4 as follows:

1,2,8

2,4,16

3,6,24

4,8,32

5,10,40

6,12,48

7,14,56

8,16,64

9,18,72

10,20,80

I just cant find any instructions about how to refer backwards to previous row values in an array and use them to produce a new value for that same column,

The simplest example would be a 1 dimensional array making a list of numbers where you started with a number and each successive row was the previous value + 1.

I realize this is probably basic stuff, but I must be searching on the  wrong term to find an answer so I turn to you. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: doesn't sound like that would solve the general problem with the slow UDFs. Might be easier to switch to Manual Calculation mode http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5925/switch-off-properties-during-macro-execution

Answer (score 3):

Did you try something like

```
Myarr(i,2)=Myarr(i-1,2)+const
```

Comment: Thanks h2so4! I certainly will try it.

Comment: Having syntax problems. What is wrong with this code?                              Sub newsub()                                                                                          Dim myarr(0 To 9, 0 To 2) As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    
For i = LBound(myarr, 0) To UBound(myarr, 0)
         j = myarr(i, 0) = myarr(i - 1, 0) + 2
         
Next i
Debug.Print i, j

End Sub

Comment: @joshuad the dimensions indices are 1-based. Use `LBound(myarr, 1)`, `UBound(myarr, 1)`,  `LBound(myarr, 2)` and `UBound(myarr, 2)`,

Comment: I'm afraid this still isnt working, but not sure why. <br/>Sub newsub()<br/>
    Dim myarr(1 To 9, 0 To 2) As Variant<br/>
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer<br/>
    
    For i = LBound(myarr, 1) To UBound(myarr, 1)<br/>
        j = myarr(i - 1, 2) + 2<br/>
    Next i<br/>
Debug.Print i, j<br/>
End Sub<br/> Sorry!

Comment: That's because `myarr(i-1, 2)` is out of bounds when `i = LBound(myarr, 1)`. You should start the iteration at `For i = LBound(myarr, 1) +1 to ...`. And btw better `Dim myarr(1 To 10, 1 To 3)`.

Comment: I apologize for my terrible html skills here. But I seem to have found a syntax that provides a technique I think I can use, thanks to you all. I tried this and it produced the expected sort of result:

Comment: Sub newsub()
    Dim myarr(1 To 10, 1 To 3) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
        
    For i = LBound(myarr, 1) To UBound(myarr, 1)
        j = j + 4
        k = j * 2
        Debug.Print i, j, k
    Next i
    
 End Sub

Comment: @joshuad, the code in your last comment doesn't output the values as per your example